# flux.take(x) or flux.all(..) doesn't wait for all emissions

Tags: java, rx-java, project-reactor

I have a `flux` that is built from an `Iterable` of 8 elements (`Flux.fromIterable(..)`).
Per each of the flux emissions, I want to invoke asynchronously a method.
I tried various ways with `dispatchOn` and `publishOn` that didn’t work and eventually I settled with `map(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(..), executor)` which transforms the `flux` to `flux<CompletableFuture<Boolean>>`.

Now I want to continue the flow only when the last item completes.
I tried with `all(..)`, and with `take(size of the Iterable)` but in both cases the flow continues before all the elements have completed.
I assume that this is because my executor has only 4 threads and it takes some time for the `CompletableFuture`-s to be added into the flux.

Why doesn’t `all(..)` or `take(8)` wait for the flux to complete?
How can I make it wait?

The code:

```
    Mono
    .fromFuture(dbUtil.getEntity(id))
    .doOnError(t -> {
        ...
        return;})
    .doOnSuccess(s -> log.info("Got it: " + s))
    .flatMap( s -> 
        Flux.fromIterable(s.getItemsMap().entrySet())
            .map( e -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->process(e, s), EXECUTOR))
            .take(s.getItemsMap().entrySet().size()) 
    )
    .all(...)
    .consume(b -> done(b));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go parallel with a computation for each item, you can use flatMap+just+subscribeOn+map. I'm not too familiar with Reactor's scheduler types so I'll give you an example in RxJava:

```
ExecutorService exec = ...
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.from(exec);

Observable.from(...)
.flatMap(e -> Observable.just(e).subscribeOn(scheduler).map(v -> process(v)))
.subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Thanks @akarnokd. I tried your suggestion but got messed up with it and due to time pressure I must put it aside for now. Anyway, if I understand correctly the outcome should be pretty much similar to what I tried with reactor, just maybe the `subscribeOn` instead of `dispatchOn`/`publishOn` could made some difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would try add in your observable

```
 .finallyDo("here arrive when onComplete or onError")
```

Because I can assume that you cannot create an observable per iterator, then merge or zip all of them and just subscribe it.

```
   Observable.merge(obsevableIter1(), observableIter2())
              .subscribe(result -> showResult(result.toString()));
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul. I looked at `finnalyDo` but it doesn’t seem to fit here since I don’t want any emissions to pass through until the Flux (/observable) completes.